# Unable to get date from string

Tags: php, date

I have date in a string as follows:

```
$rawDate = "08/08/2017 - 21/09/2017";
```

To separate two dates from each other I used code as:

```
$dates = explode("-", $rawDate);
```

Now I want to print dates as Date1 and Date2 as follows:

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dates[0])); 
echo "Date 1: " . $date1;
echo "<br/>";
$date2 =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dates[1]));
echo "Date 2: " . $date2;
```

I want result as
Date 1: 2017-08-08
Date 2: 2017-09-21

But I am getting result as
Date 1: 2017-08-08
Date 2: 2017-01-01

Can anyone help me how this is happening??

Comment: The wonders of `d/m/Y` and `m/d/Y`.... PHP's [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) [treats dates with a `/` as US format (`m/d/Y`)](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) and there is no month 21 in any year

Comment: *"I want result as
Date 1: 2017-08-08
Date 2: 1970-09-21"* - Funny, the second date is `21/09/2017`, why would you want that as `1970-09-21`?

Comment: I don't think DD/MM/YY is a valid format

Comment: Shouldn't you explode by `' - '`, not `'-'`? Just a note

Comment: Is this the format you always need to work with; have you any control? `$rawDate = "08/08/2017 - 09/21/2017";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
$rawDate = "08/08/2017 - 21/09/2017";
$dates = explode(" - ", $rawDate);

$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$dates[0]))); 
echo "Date 1: " . $date1;
echo "<br/>";
$date2 =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$dates[1])));
echo "Date 2: " . $date2;
```

Answer (score 6):

Life is a lot easier working with dates if you use DateTime objects, because it's easy to specify the format you're receiving the dates

```
$rawDate = "08/08/2017 - 21/09/2017";

$dates = explode("-", $rawDate);

$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', trim($dates[0])); 
echo "Date 1: " . $date1->format('Y-m-d');
echo PHP_EOL;
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', trim($dates[1])); 
echo "Date 2: " . $date2->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Side note: `echo PHP_EOL;` will only appear as a new line in HTML source of if written to a file/database. If the output is to appear as a new line on screen, it should either be replaced or appended with `<br>`.